# C# connect Progress Database Error

Tags: c#, database, odbc, openedge, progress-db

I want to connect progress database in local with c#.

my c# code is:

```
 string connectionString = "DSN=OpenEdge Wire Protocol;Host = localhost; DB = E:\\programs\\DBs\\TrDB\\trnakdb; UID = connuser; PWD = 123456; PORT = 11112";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        int rows;

        using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
        using (OdbcCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        using (OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(command))
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM PUB.FTTEFBAS";
            rows = adapter.Fill(dt);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("adapter.Fill() returned {0}", rows);
        Console.WriteLine("The data table contains {0} rows and {1} columns.",
          dt.Rows.Count,
          dt.Columns.Count
          );
        foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows)
        {
            string babili = dataRow.ItemArray.ToString()+"####";
            for (int key = 0; key < dataRow.ItemArray.Length; ++key)
                babili += "\t" + key + "=>" + dataRow.ItemArray[key];

            Console.WriteLine(babili);
        }
```

But it gives error:

```
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [HY000] [DataDirect][ODBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver][OPENEDGE]Access denied (Authorisation failed) (7512)
```

I can connect with progress data dictinary or data administration tools with this username.

If I try select system tables, no errors occur. But when I try to list any table from PUB schema, it gives error.

Thanks

M. Yasin Birer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DBA needs to grant SQL permissions to your userid.  The dictionary etc use 4GL permissions which, by default, are wide open.  SQL grants are, by default, restrictive.

If you know the DBA userid (often "sysprogress") and password you could try that to prove out your connectivity.  And grant perms to users as needed.

You may find this kbase helpful:  http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/20143/p

Comment: I dont know DBA password. I setup trial version of progress openedge 11.6 to my local server. Is there any default password for sysprogress?

Comment: By default I think it is blank.   Or perhaps "sysprogress".

Comment: I fixed problem. It deleted. I have created new one.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: For reference, the permissions for the sysprogress "user" are setup in the SQL side of the database but there is no user. Authorization needs to be given to a usernames for them to be able to do anyting (i.e. query a table) but any username & any password (including a blank) can be used to login into the database (only exception is the sysprogress username. As it has special rights, it only works once authentication is turned on and the user account has to be created to be used). Once the first user is created authentication is turned on and blank passwords no longer are acceptable. HTH